# It turns a blind eye to .ruby-version

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

In a Rails directory I have a file .ruby-version:

```
1.9.3-p392
```

I have this version installed, even so the main version of Ruby I use is `2.1.2`. But for that project I need `1.9.3`

In Gemfile I also have this:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

ruby "1.9.3"
```

But nonetheless when I go to this directory in the terminal, it says:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392'
```

But as I said:

```
$ rvm list


 ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
 ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

P.S. I also have another warning but I figure it's not related to this issue:

```
$ rvm list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.2'.

rvm rubies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.ruby-version` file requires `1.9.3-p392`. But you have installed `ruby-1.9.3-p547`. That are different versions.

To solve this problem install `ruby-1.9.3-p392` (what the error message tells you):

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

Or change your `.ruby-version` file to `ruby-1.9.3-p547` and use that version.

Comment: Or change .ruby-version to `ruby-1.9.3`

Comment: hm, why didn't I notice this?